# How to find the neighbors of a matrix cell

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix

I have a matrix;

```
matrix="""  1 2 3
            4 5 6
            7 8 9"""
```

And I want to find all neighbors of the given input without using third party libraries, for example output should be something like that for first row and second column which represent the number of 2 (order is not important);

```
[(2,1),(2,5),(2,3)]
```

I've found the coordinates of the neighbors with the following code but I couldn't find the neighbors:

```
lst=[i.strip().split() for i in matrix.splitlines()]
lst1=[]
def main(x,y):
    neighbors = [(x+a[0], y+a[1]) for a in [(-1,0), (1,0), (0,-1), (0,1)] if ( (0 <= x+a[0] < len(lst[0])) and (0 <= y+a[1] < len(lst)))]
    lst1.append(((x,y),neighbors))
```

Comment: What have you tried?  How is the data getting passed in?  Any code?

Comment: how is the matrix actually stored?

Answer (score 0):

```
def neighbours(pos, matrix):
    rows = len(matrix)
    cols = len(matrix[0]) if rows else 0
    for i in range(max(0, pos[0] - 1), min(rows, pos[0] + 2)):
        for j in range(max(0, pos[1] - 1), min(cols, pos[1] + 2)):
            if (i, j) != pos:
                yield matrix[i][j]
```